# LDAP with multiple domains(.net & .com)

Tags: authentication, openldap, ubuntu-9.10, domain

I have `LDAP` service running on Ubuntu server. I use `webmin` to administer ldap service of the base dn `mydomain.net`. Is it possible runnig LDAP on multiple domains?, like I want to create one more different root domain `mydomian2.com` along with `mydomain.net` in ldap. Please share ideas if anybody has any.

Thanks!

Comment: See also [Q828490](https://serverfault.com/questions/828490/setting-up-multiple-domain-in-ldap-server).

Answer (score 2):

What, specifically are you trying to do?

If you want to create a second LDAP tree you need a higher level root - You can base your tree at `o=MyCompany`, and have two Domain-Component trees under it (`dc=mydomain2,dc=com,o=MyCompany` & `dc=mydomain,dc=net,o=MyCompany`).
If you want to be pedantic (and if LDAP allows it) you can root your tree at `dc=.` as well in true DNS fashion.

---

If you just want to have two systems authenticate against the same LDAP data I wouldn't worry so much about the name.  If you want to worry about it consider using an [LDAP Referral](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch7/referrals.html) if all your systems support it...

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the link!. I'm no much good at ldap so I'm using webmin only for ldap instead using ldap commands. I want to configure ldap with 2 different root domains so that I can use them for authentication. There was an options in webmin which says `Tree` but when I try to create `mydomain2.com` it says `Failed... no proper global knowledge`.

Answer (score 0):

Reviving this to help out others. Zytrax demonstrates how to maintain one LDAP directory (DIT) across multiple servers/domains using syncrepl.

http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch7/index.html#ol-syncrepl-rap-slapd

> Replication features allow LDAP DIT updates to be copied to one or more LDAP systems for backup and/or performance reasons. In this context it is worth emphasizing that replication operates at the DIT level not the LDAP server level. Thus, in a single server running multiple DITs each DIT may be replicated to a different server. Replication occurs periodically within what this guide calls the replication cycle time.

---

I'm interested in seeing if anyone has documentation on how to have multiple domains point to a single LDAP server for binding authentication, instead of syncronizing multiple servers.

For example, connecting to dev.example.com would authenticate against an LDAP DIT in auth.example.com, allowing the user to be authenticated within dev.example.com.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Your answer currently does not seem to provide a workable solution to the question and might be more appropriate as a question. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask) And don't forget to take the [site tour](http://serverfault.com/tour).