# Setting Up multiple domain in LDAP server

Tags: ldap, domain-controller, centos7, openldap

I am trying to setup an LDAP server from scratch on a CENTOS 7 server. I was able to install it properly, but when it came to configuring it I am a bit stuck on the initial part.

The thing is the company I am setting this up for has 3 domains like:

- example.com
- example.in
- example-new.com

I am following this [tutorial](http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/step-step-openldap-server-configuration-centos-7-rhel-7.html).

How is can I setup 3 different **dc** for a single LDAP server

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer to that is dependent on how you want to use the LDAP server.

- If you want to have three complete separate LDAP trees, you would configure multiple databases in the `cn=config` configuration with the `olcDatabase` object type. Note that if you do it this way, you would need to setup a separate LDAP connection for each LDAP tree and you can't search for objects in other domains at all.
- If you just want a logical separation, e.g. having separate mail accounts for each domain, you would just add a junction point at appropriate branches in the tree. Something like `ou=example.com,cn=users,dc=example,dc=com` and `ou=example.in,cn=users,dc=example,dc=com` where each `cn` would hold the users for a subdomain. Depending on your needs, you would have multiple such junction points, other options might be `cn=groups,dc=example,dc=com` or `cn=sites,dc=example,dc=com`. 
  This way, you can either search for users in `ou=example.com,cn=users,dc=example,dc=com` and find only users for that domain or you can search more globally in `cn=users,dc=example,dc=com` and find all users.
- A third approach is to have multiple subtrees,e.g. `ou=example.com,dc=example,dc=com` and `ou=example.in,dc=example,dc=com` and then have sub containers for actual objects like `cn=users,ou=example.com,dc=example,dc=com`. Note that while this approach offers better separation, it often turns out to be quite inefficient, as you now have to search the whole tree if you want to find an object in any of the domains.

An illustration:

- Variant 1:

  ```
  dc=example,dc=com
      cn=users
      cn=groups
  ------------------  Complete separation
  dc=example,dc=in
      cn=users
      cn=groups
  ```
- Variant 2

  ```
  dc=example,dc=com
      cn=users                <---- Junction point
          ou=example.com
              uid=alice
              uid=bob
          ou=example.in 
              uid=claire
      cn=groups               <---- Junction point
           ou=example.com
              cn=accounting
           ou=example.in
              cn=hr
  ```
- Variant 3

  ```
  dc=example,dc=com 
      ou=example.com
          cn=users
          cn=groups
      ou=example.in
          cn=users
          cn=groups
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, really helped me a lot to understand the structure of the data. I am really new to LDAP :)

Comment: Is there no way to have a common root that doesn't imply choosing `dc=example,dc=com` over `dc=example,dc=in`
Something like `dc=example,dc=com,o=commonroot`?
So we could do `cn=users,o=commonroot` and use them in the tree in each domain `dc=example,dc=com,o=commonroot`.

Comment: @Dolanor: You can do quite a lot with things like referrals etc., but this depends on what you want to do specifically and I guess also on the LDAP implementation used and maybe even the client software - some stuff that nominally "supports LDAP" is quite inflexible with non-standard tree structures.

Comment: It is OpenLDAP, so I guess it follows the standard as much as it can. But again, I'm not knowledgeable in LDAP at all.
What I want to do is to have an LDAP that enables me to have the same password on different services via LDAP directly (for smtp, imap, owncloud, gitea, etc) and that can act as background storage for coreos/dex (oauth2) to also do same password for multiple services.